# Functional derivative of $u \mapsto R\left(\int_{\Theta} \phi(\theta) \; \text{d}u(\theta)\right) + \lambda u(\Theta)$ for matrix-valued measure $u$

Tags: functional-analysis, matrix-calculus, nonlinear-optimization, frechet-derivative, vector-measure

Let $\Theta$ be a [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_manifold) connected [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Mathematical_definition), $H$ and $F$ [Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Definition) and $R \colon H \to \mathbb R$ and $\phi \colon \Theta \to F$ smooth.

> What is the [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Functional_derivative) of
> $$f(u) := R\left(\int_{\Theta} \phi(\theta) \; \text{d}u(\theta)\right) + \lambda u(\Theta),$$
> where $u \in M(\Theta; S^{N})$ is [*real symmetric $N \times N$ matrix-valued* measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_measure#Definitions_and_first_consequences) on $\Theta$?
> For this integral to well defined, we need a bounded bilinear product $$F \times S^N \to H$$ (see e.g [R. Bartle: A general vector integral](https://eudml.org/doc/216873)), which exists, but I don't specify which one.

I can calculate the [Frechet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition) of $f$: Let $v \in M(\Theta; S^N)$.
We decompose the smooth part of the objective function $f$ as $f = R \circ \Phi$, where
\begin{align*}
        \Phi \colon M(\Theta; S^N) \to H, \qquad
        v \mapsto \int_{\Theta} \phi(\theta) \; \text{d}{v}(\theta)
    \end{align*}
is a linear map between [real vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition_and_basic_properties).
Hence $D \Phi(v)[\sigma] = \Phi(\sigma)$ for all $\sigma \in M(\Theta; S^N)$.

Since $R \colon H \to \mathbb R$ is real-valued, there is the following [relation between its gradient $\nabla R \colon H \to H^*$ and its Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Relationship_with_derivative): $D R(x)[h] = \langle \nabla R(x), h \rangle_{H^* \times H}$ for $x, h \in H$.
The linearity of the Frechet derivative and the chain rule applied to $J$ yields
\begin{align*}
        (D f)(v)[\sigma]
        & = (D R)\big(\Phi(v)\big)\big[ (D\Phi)(v)[\sigma]\big]
        = \left\langle \nabla R\big(\Phi(v)\big),  \Phi(\sigma) \right\rangle_{H^* \times H} \\
        & = \left\langle \nabla R\left(\int_{\Theta} \phi(\theta) \; \text{d}v(\theta)\right), \int_{\Theta} \phi(\theta) \; \text{d}\sigma(\theta) \right\rangle_{H^* \times H}.
    \end{align*}

If I understood correctly, the functional derivative of $J$ with respect to $u$, $\frac{\delta f}{\delta u}$, has to satisfy
$$
(D f)(v)[\sigma]
= \int_{\Theta} \frac{\delta f}{\delta u}(\theta) \; \text{d}\sigma(\theta).
$$
If the measures were real-valued (i.e. $N = 1$), then I could pull out the integral from the second term in the dual pairing $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{H^* \times H}$ to get $\frac{\delta f}{\delta u}(\theta) = \left\langle \nabla R\left(\int_{\Theta} \phi(\tilde\theta) \; \text{d}v(\tilde\theta)\right), \phi(\theta) \right\rangle_{H^* \times H}$ (as it is done in [Lénaïc Chizat: Sparse optimization on measures with over-parameterized gradient descent](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-021-01636-z)), but in higher dimension I can not.

> Is there a way to still express the functional derivative of $f$, without specifying a product?

### Update

Suppose $F = S^N$ and the bilinear product is the usual [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), can the question be answered then?